# is it possible to change the emulator hosts mapping when using android studio to debug

Tags: flutter

when I start debbugging the flutter app in macOS 13.2, the log shows this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = dev-ai.poemhub.top, port = 56684
#0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
#1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:586:9)
<asynchronous suspension>

#0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:618:7)
#1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
#2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
#3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
#5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
#6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_imp<…>
```

I have added the local debbugging host mapping in macOS 13.2 `/etc/hosts` file. Seems the emulator did not using this host mapping. Is it possible to make the emulator recogonize the host mapping? or where can I configure the domain? this is the macOS domain mapping config:

```
127.0.0.1       dev-ai.poemhub.top
```